# Removing blue links in an image map HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, imagemap

I'm building an e-mail for a client with a html map. However I can't seem to get the blue line around links (after they are clicked) to disappear.

I need help.

```html
<p> <br>
      <img alt="Hogan" src="http://lsa5.0.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/club_DEM_HK-LifeStyleAsia.jpg"
        style="border-style: none"
        usemap="#map1417501545030"><map
        border:="0"
        border-color="transparent"
        id="map1417501545030"
        name="map1417501545030"
        usemap="#map1417501545030]">
        border:="0" <area alt="" border="0" coords="300,115,347,132" href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&amp;c=20&amp;mc=click&amp;pli=11769974&amp;PluID=0&amp;ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
          shape="alt=&quot;&quot;"
          target="_self"
          title="">
        <area alt="" border="0" coords="9,925,631,1527" href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&amp;c=20&amp;mc=click&amp;pli=11769971&amp;PluID=0&amp;ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
          shape="rect"
          target="_self"
          title="">
        <area alt="" border="0" coords="329,681,632,911" href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&amp;c=20&amp;mc=click&amp;pli=11769977&amp;PluID=0&amp;ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
          shape="rect"
          target="_self"
          title="">
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. Could you describe how exactly to reproduce your problem and what behavior is expected?

Comment: When we preview the page in Chrome or send it to any e-mail browser a blue line around the link appears. We are trying to get rid of these blue lines around the links here are the original [link]http://send.lifestyleasia.com/t/ViewEmail/r/D949229CF51520BA2540EF23F30FEDED

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
style=" outline: none;"
```

to the element of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Below should do the trick:

```
 style="outline: none;"
```

And here i've added it to your HTML.

```html
<p> <br>
      <img alt="Hogan" src="http://lsa5.0.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/club_DEM_HK-LifeStyleAsia.jpg"
        style="border-style: none"
        usemap="#map1417501545030"><map
        border:="0"
        border-color="transparent"
        id="map1417501545030"
        name="map1417501545030"
        usemap="#map1417501545030]">
        border:="0" <area alt="" border="0" coords="300,115,347,132" href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&amp;c=20&amp;mc=click&amp;pli=11769974&amp;PluID=0&amp;ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
          shape="alt=&quot;&quot;"
          target="_self"
          title="" style="outline: none;">
        <area alt="" border="0" coords="9,925,631,1527" href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&amp;c=20&amp;mc=click&amp;pli=11769971&amp;PluID=0&amp;ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
          shape="rect"
          target="_self"
          title="" style="outline: none;">
        <area alt="" border="0" coords="329,681,632,911" href="http://bs.serving-sys.com/BurstingPipe/adServer.bs?cn=tf&amp;c=20&amp;mc=click&amp;pli=11769977&amp;PluID=0&amp;ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%"
          shape="rect"
          target="_self"
          title="" style="outline: none;">
```